# PFObject getting corrupted somewhere in the app when calling cloud code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8, pfobject, local-datastore

Okay, I promise I couldn't have come up with a better title. I'm on the latest (1.6.4) Parse iOS SDK and I roughly have a `Post` class with a `comments` field which is a number. I call a cloud function, and upon completion, my post object's fields are gone. Anything other than the `objectId` is `nil`. If I fetch (forcefully, `ifNeeded` doesn't work as well) then it loads again. But meanwhile, my client-side data gets corrupted. This happens on `PFUser` class too, and it happens only after calling something at the cloud. Am I doing something wrong, or is it a very serious bug at Parse iOS SDK?

I am also using local datastore (since my whole app has many calls to it, I can't just disable and test it), if it helps.

Comment:  bro. Ha. Anyways, it sounds like you might be creating a new object (or its properties) as opposed to updating it. But can't say for sure without references. Show your code...bro. Ha

Comment: @soulshined the code is a mess, really, too many things at different files. but the original idea applies. I'm not creating a new object. the reference to  old objects (they are THE same old object, the memory address is the same) are the same, the object itself is being modified by the internals of the Parse SDK (which I don't have access to).

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu i think the Cloud Code should suffice, at minimum. Since that's the root issue. As far as I know, this is a targeted circumstance, haven't seen any other issues like this (on SO or the parse google group). I doubt its not a human error at this point, but only you can truly know since you see the project everyday. Cloud Functions can be tricky, specifically the callbacks (error) placements

Comment: @soulshined I think we've nailed down the solution with my friend. in the cloud function, I was returning the newly created object (comment). however, that object was only having a pointer (object itself NOT included) to the sending user, which is the current user. for some reason (probably something poorly implemented at the inner Parse SDK) that unincluded object (PFObject with only an objectId field) was taking place of the loaded objects automatically upon cloud code completion, which caused corruption of the legit objects. we forced to include full user object in cloud and it's working.

Comment: makes sense @CanPoyrazoğlu glad your good to go